# Не работает Yii::t()

Tags: yii2

Хочу использовать на сайте переводы фраз. Создал в `common\messages\` необходимые переводы. Где нужно вставить на сайте перевод, делаю так

```
Yii::t('app', 'Главная')
```

При переключении языка на английский все равно пишет Главная, хотя в файле `common\messages\en\app.php` пишет

```
<?php
return [
    'Главная' => 'Home'
];
```

В файле `frontend\config\main.php` задал такие параметры

```
'language' => 'ru',
'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
```

Если после переключения языка вывести `Yii::$app->language` то показывает `en`

Помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так

Только что увидел, что не переопределяется класс

```
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'ua',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

Но оно по прежнему использует `yii\i18n\MessageSource`

Comment: в самой функции `t()` делаю `var_dump($language)` и получаю NULL

Comment: дошел до файла `/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/MessageSource.php`, у него есть функция `loadMessages`, она не загружается нужный перевод. То есть, если вывожу загруженный перевод, то для каждой фразы стоит `false`

Comment: 'language' => 'ru-RU',